# Snowflake SQL: Convert Transactional Data into Periodic Snapshots for Time Series Analysis in Tableau

Tags: sql, time-series, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snapshot

Using Snowflake SQL, I need to convert the following transactional data into periodic (month-end) snapshots for time series analysis in Tableau.

The data I have is transactional, showing the date they changed departments, and the new department they are in.  I need to be able to show 36 months of snapshots (a list of which department each employee was in as of the end of each month).  Employees can change departments on any date, and change departments multiple times (and so have multiple records), or not at all (they have a single record).

Input (Transactional Data I have):

```
| emp_id  | department_code | effective_date |
| -------------------------------------------|
| 1       | 100             | 7/15/2022      |
| 1       | 200             | 10/2/2022      |
| 1       | 100             | 11/10/2022     |
| 2       | 300             | 8/31/2022      |
| 2       | 500             | 10/15/2022     |
| 2       | 400             | 10/31/2022     |
| 3       | 100             | 1/1/2022       |
| 4       | 200             | 5/3/2022       |
```

Desired Output (Format I need to import into Tableau - I need 36 monthly snapshots generated, but using 4 to illustrate the principle):

```
|emp_id  | department_code | snapshot_date |
| -----------------------------------------|
|1       | 100             | 11/30/2022    |
|2       | 400             | 11/30/2022    |
|3       | 100             | 11/30/2022    |
|4       | 200             | 11/30/2022    |
|1       | 200             | 10/31/2022    |
|2       | 400             | 10/31/2022    |
|3       | 100             | 10/31/2022    |
|4       | 200             | 10/31/2022    |
|1       | 100             | 9/30/2022     |
|2       | 300             | 9/30/2022     |
|3       | 100             | 9/30/2022     |
|4       | 200             | 9/30/2022     |
|1       | 100             | 8/31/2022     |
|2       | 300             | 8/31/2022     |
|3       | 100             | 8/31/2022     |
|4       | 200             | 8/31/2022     |
```

I'm able to do one monthly snapshot, or multiple by unioning one together with others, but I am sure there is a better way to write this recursively.

Answer (score 0):

the input data as a CTE to make it easier for me:

```
with emp_data(emp_id, dep_id, date) as (
    select * from values
        (1, 100, '2022-7-15'::date),
        (1, 200, '2022-10-2'::date), 
        (1, 100, '2022-11-10'::date),
        (2, 300, '2022-8-31'::date),
        (2, 500, '2022-10-15'::date),
        (2, 400, '2022-10-31'::date),
        (3, 100, '2022-1-1'::date),
        (4, 200, '2022-5-3'::date)
)
```

and the body of the SQL as:

```
with last_36_months as (
    select 
        row_number() over(order by null)-1 as q_level,
        last_day(dateadd(month, - q_level, CURRENT_DATE), month) as last_day_month
    --from table(generator(ROWCOUNT=>36))
    from table(generator(ROWCOUNT=>4))
), month_end_data as (
    select 
        e.emp_id
        ,e.dep_id
        ,l.last_day_month as month
    from last_36_months as l
    join emp_data as e
        on e.date <= l.last_day_month
    qualify row_number() over(partition by e.emp_id, l.last_day_month order by e.date desc) = 1
)
select * 
from month_end_data
order by 3 desc, 1;
```

gives:

| EMP_ID | DEP_ID | MONTH |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 2022-11-30 |
| 2 | 400 | 2022-11-30 |
| 3 | 100 | 2022-11-30 |
| 4 | 200 | 2022-11-30 |
| 1 | 200 | 2022-10-31 |
| 2 | 400 | 2022-10-31 |
| 3 | 100 | 2022-10-31 |
| 4 | 200 | 2022-10-31 |
| 1 | 100 | 2022-09-30 |
| 2 | 300 | 2022-09-30 |
| 3 | 100 | 2022-09-30 |
| 4 | 200 | 2022-09-30 |
| 1 | 100 | 2022-08-31 |
| 2 | 300 | 2022-08-31 |
| 3 | 100 | 2022-08-31 |
| 4 | 200 | 2022-08-31 |

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative where we start by resolving department changes in the same month-->Then stack 36 month end permutations for each **emp_id** on top of it, with **dep_id** being **null** for the time being--> Finally, look back to populate  **null dep_ids** with most the recent one available to complete the snapshot.

```
with cte as

(select distinct --start with existing dates and resolve dep_id change in the same month
        emp_id,
        first_value(dep_id) over (partition by emp_id, last_day(dates) order by dates desc) as dep_id,
        last_day(dates) as dates
 from t

 union all

 select distinct --generate all previous 36 month ends per emp_id with null dep_ids for now
       emp_id, 
       null,
       add_months(last_day(current_date),(row_number() over (partition by emp_id order by 1)-1)*-1)
 from (select distinct emp_id from t) cross join table(generator(rowcount=>36)) )
 
select distinct --look back to populate null dep_ids with most recent that's available
       emp_id, 
       coalesce(dep_id,lag(dep_id) ignore nulls over (partition by emp_id order by dates)) as dep_id,
       dates
from cte
order by emp_id,dates
```

Comment: thank you - there is one issue with this as the solution which probably could have been avoided had I been more explicit in the question parameters.  The number of rows per employee should equal the number of months between the earliest and latest month end.  Eg, if latest month end is 10/31 and the first record for a given employee is 8/15, then they should have 3 rows (8/31, 9/30 and 10/31).

Comment: @Gavin One can only answer a question within the confines of its formulation. Answering a question will all the possibilities in mind is a little futile given most people don't even accept or engage with answers. I suggest asking another question with the right requirements. Fresh questions typically get more visibility than older questions with edits so you should be able to find the help you need